# Microsoft Access VBA If statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a dropdown menu that has three options "Open, Assigned, Closed" I have three rows in a table in my database, one for openTime, assignedTime, and closedTime.

My dropdown menu is connected to a row in my table called Status which is swapped between the three options "Open, Assigned, Closed". When the ticket is created in my website, it creates an open time so I don't have to worry about that, but when the user selects assigned and closed I would like it to on change send data to the correct cell.

So if the drop down is swapped from open to assigned it already changes the status cell to "Assigned" in my database but I would also like it to change the assignedTime cell's data to the exact time and date. Same for closed.

I think this is simple I'm just a bit confused on the process. Im using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements) site for info on IF statements

I have my code that creates and adds my date

```
me.MyDateTimeColumn = now()
```

I have a few questions

1) In my IF statement how do I say the value of the selection for example if the user selects "Assigned' in the drop down menu how do I say thats the info I want my IF statement looking at?

On the site linked above this is there example for an if statement:

```
Sub AlertUser(value as Long) 
 If value = 0 Then 
 AlertLabel.ForeColor = "Red" 
 AlertLabel.Font.Bold = True 
 AlertLabel.Font.Italic = True 
 End If 
End Sub
```

On this do I need to include the `Sub AlertUser(value as Long)`(using my own variables) If so what would my sub be?
and does the `If value = 0 Then` refer to the value of the selected comboBox?

2) Can I insert an else if as I would in other languages, do I need an end else if?

I am using a microsoft access form, and using the VBA code section for this. MY database is in a sql server connected to the form.

Comment: Yes, VBA uses `If Then ElseIf Else End If` structure. Yes, use your own variables. Yes, reference your combobox control for value `If Me.comboboxname = "Assigned" Then`. Is this form in Continuous or Datasheet view? You should be aware that setting a control's properties programmatically will affect ALL instances of that control - every record will display the same. You should explore Conditional Formatting.

Comment: @June7 I think the form is continuous as it is not datasheet. I'm now realizing I can't use me.sqldatabasecolum to talk to my how do I refer or change my row in my SQL Server?

So would I be looking at If Me.Comboboxname = "Assigned" Then (However I change my sql column?) Do I need any brackets?

Comment: How you accomplish changing value in table depends on how you connect to it. If you have a link set to table and table is included in form RecordSource, just reference field name as I describe. Use `If Then ElseIf` structure as shown in the link you referenced. Another structure to learn is `Select Case`.